# Making one nested form_for use two different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models @product and @photo with @photo nested in @product. I am only allowed to use one form to create both. I am using [this JQuery plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to handle photo upload being how it gives me a nice preview.

However the plugin has certain restrictions in my create action so I cannot use the product create action to handle both creating the photo and product.

1. Is it possible to have one nested for_for use two different controllers?
2. And how would i do it ?

**my form (haml)**

```
= form_for @product,:url => products_path, :html => { id: "fileupload", multipart: true } do |f| 
  %p
    = f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name"
  %p
    = f.text_field :price, class: "auto", data: { a_sign: "$ " }, placeholder: "Price" 
  %p
    = f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description"
  %p
    = f.fields_for :photos do  |fp| 
      =fp.file_field :image
      %br

  .files{"data-target" => "#modal-gallery", "data-toggle" => "modal-gallery"}
  %p.button.start
    = f.submit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use accept_nested_attributes for to save associated data with only one create action.

Eg:-
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @album = Album.new
    @album.photos.build
  end

  def create
    @album = Albums.new(params[:album])
    @album.photos.build unless @album.photos.present?
    if @album.save  
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created albumn"
      respond_with(@album, :location => albums_path())
    else
      flash[:error] = @album.errors.full_messages
      render :new
    end
  end
end

Model:-

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc {|attr|  attr['image'].blank? }
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end

View:-
= form_for @album,:url => albums_path, :html => {multipart: true } do |f| 
  %p
    = f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name"
  %p
    = f.text_field :price, class: "auto", data: { a_sign: "$ " }, placeholder: "Price" 
  %p
    = f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description"
  %p
    = f.fields_for :photos do  |photo| 
      = photo.file_field :image
      %br

  .files
  %p.button.start
    = f.submit
```

Answer (score -1):

Use ajax to firstly upload photo and after successful response continue with product.

Comment: Can i get some sort of example??